# multiple different horizontal nav-menu bottom border colours?

Tags: jquery, html, css

What would be the best way about using the css property "border-bottom", on a horizontal nav-menu, similar to StackOverflow's above, where when hovered on, the bottom border is visible and when active, it is also visible (with a colour), but in all other instances it is not.

I have done something like this before however, I wish to be to use, for instance, 3 different colours, one for each of the 3 'options' so to speak. When I did it before, I believe I hardcoded the colour in and just made it transparent or something when clicked(was a little while ago, so I don't remember exactly!).

Am I able to do this with just css, or will I have to use jquery for the changing of colours with an `onclick` event?

Comment: try using the css :hover method, and adding an .active class to the item you have active with custom stylings on it (for active)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If im understanding you properly you can use pseudo classes like `:hover`, `:active` and so on here is a small example

```
ul li{
    display:inline;
    color:yellow;
}
ul li:hover{
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
ul li:active{
    color:red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ebdkodLL/

Hope this helps

Comment: This is kind of what I mean, except instead of all of them display blue when hovered or display red when active, have only the first on display red, the second blue, the third green. I need it for both hover an active to be the same, but active will have some other stuff in addition to the colour change to signifiy it is active. if that makes any sense at all..

Comment: You can make different css rules for them by giving each of them their own class and using that along with the above pseudo classes